# AngularJS $scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have been start learning AngularJS 1.4.7 and I can't understand completely the $scope variables.
Is this a variable inside a Angular controller "like" public variables inside a PHP class?

For example:

I have 2 functions `function1(), function2()` in `HomeCtrl.js` and a `$scope.img = null;` variable, and 2 ng-click event in template file to call these functions.

On `ng-cick` event i call the `function1` and set the value of `$scope.url` to somethig

Thereafter i call the `function2` and `console.log($.scope.url)` it retutn null. Null is the initialized value of this varaiable.

I'v just set the value of `$scope.url` in `function1` and inside `function2` value of variabel is null, why?

I have no idea why happening this.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Maybe you should share the code you have so we have an example to discuss instead of assuming a lot of things. It could be due the fact you have instantiated two different HomeControllers, both having their own url variables.

Comment: Yes you'r right. I had 2 differente controller with $scope.url variabel used in same template. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scope` is instance of `controller`.

When you declare a `controller` , `scope` will be avaiable there.

You can access scope through out that `controller`.

That's why when you change on place in a `controller` , change will be reflect everywhere in that `scope`.

Comment: @NagyErvin you are welcome . does this solved your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you literally call `$.scope.url`? Then that's a problem, it should be `$scope.url`, no dot between "$" and "scope".

Scope variables have nothing to do with variables accessibility concept (public/private/protected/etc).

They are those "magic" variables, which can be placed inside **templates** using **expressions**, which allows data-binding in Angular, i.e., your html with that "magic" scope variables, gets automatically updated by angular, when you just change their values inside your controller, like in that callback function for ng-click. (Actually it's not that easy, here we come to $watch and $digest, but if you are not writing your custom directives, and not mixing, for example, jQuery code with Angular code, you may not think about it for now).

Two-side data-binding, automatic html updates - that's the main point of $scope and $scope variables.

Scope **is not** and instance of a controller, they are different Angular entities.